# pytorch batchwise indexing

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, multi-index

I am searching for a way to do some batchwise indexing for tensors.

If I have a variable Q of size 1000, I can get the elements I want by
Q[index], where index is a vector of the wanted elements.

Now I would like to do the same for more dimensional tensors.
So suppose Q is of shape n x m and I have a index matrix of shape n x p.

My goal is to get for each of the n rows the specific p elements out of the m elements.

But Q[index] is not working for this situation.

Do you have any thoughts how to handle this?

Comment: When you say "the specific p elements out of the m elements" do you mean columns? so if Q is 5x5 you're for example looking for the 5x3 matrix formed by 3 of Q's columns that you choose?

Comment: So I want a 5x3 matrix, but it does not need to be the columns of Q.

For example index could be [[0,1,2],[2,3,1],....,]

Then in the first row of Q[index] I would like the 0 1 and 2nd element of the first Q row, and in the second row I would like to have the 2nd 3rd and first element of the second Q row.
I see that Q.gather(1,index) is returning what I want. However I would like to overwrite these values in Q, so I would love to get the values by indexing.

Comment: It indeed fits your needs. What's the problem with ```Q = Q.gather(1,index_array)```? Because I think you can't accomplish that via the normal indexing methods.

Comment: The issue is that I want to gather these elements of Q and give them a new value, while leaving the other elements as they are. But I cannot do the following assignment: Q.gather(1,index_array)= A, as it is the result of a function. If I could do indexing, I could do Q[index] = A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seem to be a simple application of [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) which doesn't require any additional reshaping of the data or index tensor:

```
>>> Q = torch.rand(5, 4)
tensor([[0.8462, 0.3064, 0.2549, 0.2149],
        [0.6801, 0.5483, 0.5522, 0.6852],
        [0.1587, 0.4144, 0.8843, 0.6108],
        [0.5265, 0.8269, 0.8417, 0.6623],
        [0.8549, 0.6437, 0.4282, 0.2792]])

>>> index
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 1],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 2]])
```

The following gather operation applied on `dim=1` return a tensor `out`, such that:

```
out[i, j] = Q[i, index[i,j]]
```

This is done with the following call of `torch.Tensor.gather` on `Q`:

```
>>> Q.gather(dim=1, index=index)
tensor([[0.8462, 0.3064, 0.2549],
        [0.5522, 0.6852, 0.5483],
        [0.1587, 0.4144, 0.8843],
        [0.8417, 0.8417, 0.8417],
        [0.6437, 0.6437, 0.4282]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the function I need. But now I got the next issue:
I want to gather the elements of Q and give them new values, while leaving the remainder unchanged. Any ideas how to solve this?

Unfortunately I cannot assign Q.gather(dim=1, index=index) = A

Comment: Then you would need to use [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html) instead: `Q.scatter(dim=1, index=index, src=A)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a look into it.